# Error: "....should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope"

Tags: pine-script

Would you please help me to get resolve this error. I am novice and converting one of the Tradingview pine script version 3 to 4 and getting following error:

Script :

```
findprevious() =>  // finds previous three points (b, c, d, e)
    ehl = iff(hl == 1, -1, 1)
    loc1 = 0.0
    loc2 = 0.0
    loc3 = 0.0
    loc4 = 0.0
    xx = 0
    for x = 1 to 1000 by 1
        if hl[x] == ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc1 := zz[x]
            xx := x + 1
            break
    ehl := hl
    for x = xx to 1000 by 1
        if hl[x] == ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc2 := zz[x]
            xx := x + 1
            break
    ehl := iff(hl == 1, -1, 1)
    for x = xx to 1000 by 1
        if hl[x] == ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc3 := zz[x]
            xx := x + 1
            break
    ehl := hl
    for x = xx to 1000 by 1
        if hl[x] == ehl and not na(zz[x])
            loc4 := zz[x]
            break
    [loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4]


a = float(na)
b = float(na)
c = float(na)
d = float(na)
e = float(na)
if not na(hl)
    [loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4] = findprevious()      (Error line 66)
    a := zz
    b := loc1
    c := loc2
    d := loc3
    e := loc4
    e
```

error:

**line 66:** The function '#f0' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.
**line 66:** The function 'findprevious' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.
Script study added to the chart`enter code here`

Comment: Please post your entire script, instead of this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

It wants functions operating on continuous data to be run in the main scope, if that makes sense. For example you'll get a similar error trying something like:

```
if x
    bullCross := crossover(close, bullLine)
```

The solution is to call your functions on the main scope so they execute each bar and then determine what to do with the output.

So maybe something like:

```
a = float(na)
b = float(na)
c = float(na)
d = float(na)
e = float(na)
[loc1, loc2, loc3, loc4] = findprevious()
if not na(hl)
    b := loc1
    c := loc2
    d := loc3
    e := loc4
```

I left out the `zz` and `e`, I don't know what the dangling `e` is doing.